# Focus out in the DialogFragment android

Tags: android

I created DialogDragment with several *TextEdit*. I didn't set *focus* in xml and java files. But when I call *show* method and dialog appear I see that focus set in the first text field. How to hide the focus ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the focus on the surrounding layout instead. by using these attributes:

```
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

This will cause the focus to be set on the layout, and not in the `EditText`.